# Flutter: how do I close all dialogs that appear on the screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

Can I view the stack of displayed widgets in Flutter and close only the dialogs that are at the top of the stack?

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
Navigator.of(ctx).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('enter the route of page you want to go'));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the Dialog is at the top of the stack then you can just use as Follows:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
//This above will only pop one at a time 


Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SingleShowPage()),
                  (Route<dynamic> route) => false
              );
//This will pop till the screen you define
```

Comment: What if I don't know how many dialogs are currently displayed and I need to close them all?

Comment: Do you have some code, so that it would be clear.I have just add some code if you want to pop till specific screen.